# Homeomorphism between $[0,1]/\sim $ and the Hawaiian Earring

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $X$ be the quotient space $[0,1]/\sim$ where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation given by $0\sim 1\sim 1/2\sim \cdots\sim 1/n \sim \cdots$.

Let $H$ (the Hawaiian Earring, aka the Infinite Earring) be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ consisting of the union of circles of radius $1/n$ and centered at $(0,1/n)$ for all $n=1,2,3,\ldots$.

I need to find a homeomorphism between $X$ and $H$.

Note: I am studying general topology, so I can't use algebraic topology.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to send a point x from [0,1] to a circle of radius x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just map $\left[\frac12,1\right]$ onto the largest circle, $\left[\frac13,\frac12\right]$ onto the largest one and so on…

That is, if $x\in(0,1]$, then $x=\frac\lambda{n+1}+\frac{1-\lambda}n$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$ and some $\lambda\in[0,1]$. Then$$f(x)=\left(\frac1n\sin(2\pi\lambda),\frac1n-\frac1n\cos(2\pi\lambda)\right).$$And, of course, $f(0)=(0,0)$.

Comment: $H$ is the union of circles centered at $(0,\frac{1}{n})$ with radius $\frac{1}{n}$ according to the statement of the problem.

Comment: That's **another** way if seeing the Hawaiian Earring. It is homeomorphic (isometric, actually) to mine. So, none of them is better than the other one. Besides, if you wanted to work with that way of seeing the Hawaiian Earring, you should have stated it from the start. We are not supposed to guess it, are we?

Comment: I thought I did state it from the start, my question reads that way exactly, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You are right: you stated it from the start. I shall edit my answer then.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.

Comment: I want to show that this map $f$ is a homeomorphism. Theorem 26.6 in Munkres says that a continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism. I can use this Theorem to show $f$ is a homeomorphism, right? [0,1] is compact, $H\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is a subspace of a Hausdorff space, hence Hausdorff. For continuity, is it enough that $n\neq0$, or should I make an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument for this?

Comment: For continuity, see $f$ as a map from $[0,1]$ onto $H$. It is clear that $f$ is continuous on each interval $\left[\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right]$. So, it is continuous on $(0,1]$. FInally, it is clear that $f(0)=\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ and that therefore $f$ is continuous on $0$ too. Then, yes, just use the fact that $[0,1]$ is compact.

Comment: Is this acceptable? For injectivity, if  $\lambda_1\neq\lambda_2$ and $n_1\neq n_2$ then $x_1=\dfrac{\lambda_1}{n_1+1}+\dfrac{1-\lambda_1}{n_1}\neq x_2=\dfrac{\lambda_2}{n_2+1}+\dfrac{1-\lambda_2}{n_2}$ where $\lambda_1\neq\lambda_2$ and $n_1\neq n_2 \Rightarrow f(x_1)=\left(\dfrac{1}{n_1}\sin(2\pi\lambda_1),\dfrac{1}{n_1}-\dfrac{1}{n_1}\cos(2\pi\lambda_1)\right)\neq\left(\dfrac{1}{n_2}\sin(2\pi\lambda_2),\dfrac{1}{n_2}-\dfrac{1}{n_2}\cos(2\pi\lambda_2)\right)=f(x_2)$

Comment: It looks right.